# Converting plane equation from $ax+by+cz=d$ to $r=a+\lambda b+\mu c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> The equation of the plane Π is
>   $$2x + 3y + 4z= 48$$ Obtain a vector equation of Π in the form
>   $r = a + λb + μc$,
>   where a, b and c are of the form **pi**, **qi + rj** and **si + tk** respectively, and where $p, q, r, s, t$ are integers

My Attempt:

$a=(p,0,0)$

$2p+3(0)+4(0)=48 \implies p=24$

---

Then for the other variables I wrote down two equations:

**(1)** $(2,3,4) \cdot (x,y,z)= (24+\lambda q+ μ s, \lambda r, μ t)$

**(2)** Cross product of $b$ and $c$ is equal to $(2,3,4)$

This gives $(rt,-qt,rs)=(2,3,4)$

---

It seems impossible to me. Too many  variables that my mind can't process. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $a$ be a point on the plane, for convenience let's say $a=\begin{pmatrix}24\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, $b$ and $c$ must be vectors that are normal to $\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}$, that is for which $\overrightarrow{b}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}=0$ and $\overrightarrow{c}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}=0$, where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.

Comment: I get $2q+3r=0$ and $2s+4t=0$ and sadly I don't know how to continue :/

Comment: Yep $b_3=0$ and $c_2=0$ . That is how I got $2q+3r=0$ and $2s+4t=0$ . How to proceed? :/

Comment: $2b_1+3b_2+4b_3=0$ gives for example $b=(3,-2,0)$ and $2c_1+3c_2+4c_3=0$ gives for example $c=(-2,0,1)$. There is not only one solution to each equation, it as infinitely many solutions, and you can pick the one that is the easiest.

Comment: Yes but please can you tell me how you find the values? Of $b_2, b_1, c_1, c_3$ ? We have 2 equations and 4 unknowns

Comment: Oh you put $b_2, b_3$ to some random value (any number that comes to your head) and then find the corresponding $b_1$ ? :D Am I correct ? :D

Comment: Yes, and it's the easiest to pick values that are simple and produce a nice answer. :)

Comment: Got it :DDDDDDDD

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In dimension two we have $(a,b)\perp (-b,a).$ This idea can be translated to $3D$ as follows:

$$(a,b,c)\perp (-b,a,0); (a,b,c)\perp (-c,0,a); (a,b,c)\perp (0,-c,b).$$

Can you get from this two vectors perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane $(2,3,4)$ satisfying the required conditions?

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ ? I don't understand :(

Comment: @TheArtist Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Im trying to understand what you mean :)

Comment: You have that $(-3,2,0), (-4,0,2)$ and $(0,-4,3)$ are vectors perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane $(2,3,4).$ Just choose the couple of vectors satisfying the required conditions.